# grub2 equalivent of bash $(cat /path/to/file)

Tags: grub2

I use grub2 to boot a Linux system. This Linux system requires a very long kernel cmdline, stored in a file at the path of `/cmdline`. This system does not have a grub configuration file, so I have to use the grub shell to boot the system manually with the `linux` command, followed by the path to a kernel image and the cmdline, and then `boot`. So I have to run `cat /cmdline`, then retype the cmdline. This is very tedious, and it would be a lot easier to do something like `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.4 $(cat /cmdline)`. I have tried the following:

```
`cat /cmdline`
 $(cat /cmdline)
 $(</cmdline)
```

So what grub/grub2 equalivents are there to the comon `$(cat /path/to/file)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no equivalent. Use `configfile /mygrub.cfg`.